# Passing Reactive Form Fields as Prop to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-template

I have two reactive forms that are very similar. I'd like to share markup code for the fields between these to forms. The problem is when I move fields to an ng-template element, I get an error because I have defined formControlName on the elements when they are not wrapped by an element with formGroup set.

How can I share field markup between forms with Reactive Form?

I've made a basic stackblitz to represent the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3qqqb

I know this can be done with template forms but I'd like to use reactive forms.

Comment: can you share stackblitz code editor link?

Comment: @Chellappan updated the post with an edit url

Comment: How about this - https://angular-bkvzvd.stackblitz.io ? If this solution fits you I can provide more detailed answer.